# Windows phone 8.1 Background Task

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I want to Sync my local SQL CE Db on everyday 8 AM and 4 PM. I am using windows background task for this. But i cannot access SQL CE lib like using System.Data.Linq; in my Windows RunTime Component project (This is the only one type of project which ca use for Background task in win phone 8.1).

Please Help....

Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Write a web service that connects to the CE DB and pass it the sync data.